# Is this only affecting Ubuntu? Rhino (JavaScript engine in Java SE 6 and 7) producing ConsString where String expected?

Tags: javascript, java, ubuntu, rhino

Now with an [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1553654), not yet replied to as of this writing. (It would still interest me to know whether anyone sees this behavior *outside* of Ubuntu.)

**A reproducer, and some versions where it is and isn't broken**

I've written a short reproducer that illustrates the problem, on the Ubuntu Trusty system used by the person reporting it to me. He sent me this summary of results:

```
Fail  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
Fail  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Fail  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
Pass  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

(Darn, I did not hound him for what exact versions those were, but he installed them just recently from the Ubunty Trusty repos. The 7 version is 1.7.0_95 as he reported before.)

I have tested the same reproducer on these versions in Red Hat, with no failure anywhere, so this is starting to look like some Ubuntu build issue.

```
Pass  OpenJDK 1.6.0_38 (rhel-1.13.10.0.el6_7-x86_64)
Pass  OpenJDK 1.7.0_95 (rhel-2.6.4.0.el6_7-x86_64 u95-b00)
Pass  OpenJDK 1.8.0_71 (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
```

Here is the reproducer. `Pass` is printing a single integer, usually zero (it might be nonzero on a platform where `echo` isn't a command `ProcessBuilder` can launch). `Fail` is an exception like the following:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java constructor for "java.lang.ProcessBuilder" with arguments "string,string,sun.org.mozilla.javascript.ConsString" not found.
```

Annnd ... here's the code:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class jstest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine testEngine =
      mgr.getEngineByMimeType( "application/javascript");

    String testScript =
"    var key = 'something';\n" +
"    var tpr = 'echo';\n" +
"    var pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(tpr, '--', '--'+key);\n" +
"    pb.start().waitFor();\n";

    System.out.println(testEngine.eval(testScript)); // success prints 0
  }
}
```

**Updated update**

The reporter of this issue (to me) has clarified that he's running an *OpenJDK* build, not (as I earlier thought) Oracle. It is apparently the OpenJDK 7
packaged for Ubuntu Trusty. I was inferring its version from the top of a Maven log running in that JVM, which comes out:

```
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

and it seems I erred in assuming that had to be Oracle's 1.7.0_95. (I'm not sure exactly which Java system properties Maven picks out to create that version line, but I've asked him to send me a full list of properties from that JVM so I can learn not to make that mistake again.)

Apologies to anyone who might have tried to reproduce the issue in *Oracle* 1.7.0_95.

**Update**

I have downloaded and tried JDK 1.7.0_80 (that is the latest member of the 1.7 series available to *non*-Oracle-paid-support customers) and the JavaScript runs with no problem. <del>Whatever change altered the behavior must have come in one of the later versions only available to Oracle support customers. That probably helps explain why it's not been more widely noticed already.</del>

<del>There are [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javase7supportreleasenotes-1601161.html) for those paid-support updates, but in skimming them so far I have not seen an obvious smoking gun yet. (Some of the releases have links to "for *all* changes see *here*" pages, and I have so far not followed *those*.)</del>

**Back to original question**

I have a small task that's done in Java's `javax.script` engine for JavaScript, which I understand was based on Rhino in Java SE 6 and 7, swapped out for Nashorn in Java SE 8. Knowing that, I was pretty careful to test it on 6, 7, and 8, and there *were* some tweaks needed to make it usable with both engines, but by the time I was done it was working perfectly everywhere.

Today I got an email from someone who is running <del>Oracle Java</del> OpenJDK 1.7.0_95 (newer than the versions I had tested) and it is failing to execute the JavaScript. The main issue seems to be that the `+` operator between two strings no longer produces a string result, it produces a `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.ConsString` instead. That doesn't behave as a regular String (it lacks a `replace` method, passing it as a parameter to a Java method expecting String produces method not found because the signature is wrong, etc.) If I edit and change every string expression `s1 + s2` to be `String(s1 + s2)` then I have a usable string again.

There seems to be another behavior change, in that this formerly worked:

`var pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(pgc, '--'+key);`

Now, of course, if I *don't* change parameter 2 to `String('--'+key)`, it fails this way:

`javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java constructor for "java.lang.ProcessBuilder" with arguments "string,sun.org.mozilla.javascript.ConsString" not found.`

So I *do* change it, but then it *still* fails, now like this:

`javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java constructor for "java.lang.ProcessBuilder" with arguments "string,string" not found.`

OK, so `ProcessBuilder` has two constructors, one declared to take `List<java.lang.String>` and one variadic (`java.lang.String...`), and the JavaScript engine never before had a problem mapping this call (with its two string parameters) to one of those.

To me these seem like bugs that have crept in, more than any likely deliberate change to the script engine; these new behaviors don't seem correct. I have not done a bisect among recent <del>Oracle</del> JRE 7 versions to find exactly when it began behaving this way. Am I the only one seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to answer this question, as the only Java versions that came with Rhino rather than Nashorn are so long past support. And even Nashorn is no longer batteries-included after Java 14, though either [standalone Nashorn](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core) or [GraalJS](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js) can be included to use JavaScript in a project.

But back to Rhino.

The Rhino implementation of JavaScript itself did not, it seems, directly include a script-engine wrapper to make it available via the [javax.script API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html). The wrapper was a small extra coding effort. Oracle may have had a version that wasn't directly available for OpenJDK, or was at a link that went dead (as [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271810/where-is-the-rhino-javascript-jsr-223-wrapper-for-use-in-jdk8) suggests). Another may have been developed independently, or starting from older code (I don't have all the details at hand). There is at least one [Maven-distributed fork](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cat.inspiracio/rhino-js-engine/1.7.7.1) with the sources [here](https://bitbucket.org/bunkenburg/rhino-js-engine/src/master/).

Problems like certain instances of Rhino's `ConsString` not getting made into Java `String` existed in certain versions of the engine wrapper that were included in certain builds of OpenJDK. They did not represent behavior changes or regressions in Rhino itself.